# Testclass for emailmessage invocable method

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

Im trying to write a tesclass for an email message but i keep getting the error:

> Line 21 Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [SendemailController].sendEmailFunction(Id)

here are my class and testclass:

```
public class SendemailController {

    @InvocableMethod(label='Send an email from apex class' description='sends an email')

public static void  sendEmailFunction(List<id> LeadId) { 

Lead getEmail = [SELECT Id, Email_Klant__c FROM Lead WHERE id =: LeadId];
   if(getEmail.Email_Klant__c != null) {
     String toaddress = getEmail.Email_Klant__c;
       system.debug(getEmail);

List<id> ids = new List<id>();
for(Lead curr:[Select (select Id from signrequest__SignRequests__r) from Lead WHERE Lead.Id=:LeadId]){
  for(signrequest__SignRequest__c ss : curr.signrequest__SignRequests__r){
     ids.add(ss.id);  
  }
}
system.debug('ids'+ ids);

Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
String[] toAddresses = new String[] {toaddress};
String[] ccAddresses = new String[] {toaddress};
mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
mail.setCcAddresses(ccAddresses);
mail.setReplyTo(toaddress);
mail.setSenderDisplayName('Name');
mail.setSubject('Testing email through apex');
mail.setBccSender(false);
mail.setUseSignature(true);
mail.setPlainTextBody('Dear tester, here are the attachments. This mail is sent trough apex');


List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> fileAttachments = new List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();        
 for (Attachment a : [select Name, Body, BodyLength from Attachment where ParentId IN :ids AND (NOT Name LIKE '%log.pdf')]){
   Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
   efa.setFileName(a.Name);
   efa.setBody(a.Body);
   fileAttachments.add(efa);
 }        
system.debug('fileAttachments'+ fileAttachments);

mail.setFileAttachments(fileAttachments);
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });  
    }       
   }
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest
private class SendemailControllerTest{
static testMethod void test () {

     Lead Le = new Lead();
     Le.Company= 'company';
     Le.Achternaam_Contactpersoon_SV_Pay__c = 'achternaam';
     Le.Status = 'Nieuw';
     Le.Email_Klant__c = 'test@test.com';
     Le.Email_SV_Pay__c = 'test@test.com';
     Insert Le;

     Attachment att = new Attachment();
     att.Name = 'test';
     att.Body = Blob.ValueOf('test');
     att.ParentId = Le.id;
     Insert att;

    SendemailController Controller = new SendemailController();

    Controller.sendEmailFunction(Le.Id);

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, the code is expecting a list, so you need to give it one. Also, the method is static, so you must use the class name instead of an instance.

```
/* No need to make an "instance" to access static members ***
SendemailController Controller = new SendemailController();
*/

SendemailController.sendEmailFunction(new Id[] { Le.Id });
```

Comment: That helped but 0 coverage :(

Comment: @Jenssen Looks like your unit test should be failing. Last Name is a required field for Lead.

Comment: Ahh you right that did it 81% thanks!! but its weird that the dev console didnt give me an error?

Comment: @Jenssen The "Tests" tab should have shown the test with a red X next to it, indicating the failure.

Comment: Indeed but this time no red X weird?! Normally you cant save or get the message failed insert but this time I could save the test without errors.

Comment: @Jenssen saing successfully is nt an indication of a test success. You need to make sure you're looking at the Tests tab.